# find and replace bunch of XML tags

Tags: regex, shell, vim, scripting

I have simple question. I have one huge file containing millions of data in XML format. I have to find all the tags like below and replace them with nothing. Any help please with vim or sed ?

```
    <dtlsEntry>
    <dataTyp></dataTyp>
    <dataDtls></dataDtls>
    </dtlsEntry>
```

If you observe this, no value is present in the xml tags . And i want to delete the complete XML from  dtlsEntry to dtlsEntry

Comment: Obligatory [Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) link; with "millions of data", it's hard to verify that the same format is consistently used (unless you know the XML source by heart), and an XML tool (like `xsltproc`) is preferable.

Comment: lets not consider it as 'milions'. let it be 1000 such XML tags..

Comment: Could you post a quick example of the input and example output that you want? I want to be 100% sure I know what you mean before I take a look.

Comment: Hi , input will be this :             <dtlsEntry>
    <dataTyp></dataTyp>
    <dataDtls></dataDtls>
    </dtlsEntry> and output should be nothing

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments,  doing this reliably with a single regex could be difficult or impossible in a general case. But you may have a very specific case. Add any complexity, and it gets ugly very fast. *If comments in the XML are never there, and neither are attributes, and if the ordering is guaranteed*, this should do it in Vim but it may be slow:

```
:%s#<dtlsEntry\_s*>\_s*<dataTyp\_s*></dataTyp\_s*>\_s*<dataDtls\_s*></dataDtls\_s*>\_s*</dtlsEntry\_s*>##
```

The only trick I used here was inserting `\_s*` where ever arbitrary whitespace is allowed, to match any whitespace including newlines. You may need to add more of those if you can have whitespace inside the dataTyp tag, for example. But again, note all the caveats and limitations above. Removing any of these limitations will add complexity; in fact allowing full comments support in particular may make it nearly impossible.

Comment: Hi Ben , there will be no comments in XML ; nor attributes; ordering is guaranteed. I have tried your command in vim and it was working . let me write a wrapper script. thanks a ton !!